# ASP.NET System.Data.EntityClient connection string help (Entities)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, database-connection

i have inherited some code form another developer who is using entityClient for a connection string. the web config entry looks like:

```
<add name="my_TESTEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/TEST.csdl|res://*/TEST.ssdl|res://*/TEST.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=myServer;Initial Catalog=TEST2;User ID=user_gg;Password=Aasdfasfasf;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
```

what are the metadata files? i found them in the debug folder of the code i was given, do i need to point to them? do i need to move them somewhere else?  please help!

the error i'm getting is:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A
>   network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing
>   a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not
>   accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL
>   Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Comment: In the metadata files is where are generated the mappings between the database and the classes of your project. But Do you have a Error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your meta data files are: TEST.csdl, TEST.ssdl and TEST.msl.

They are populated by a Entity Framework EDMX. You can look into these files by changing value of the property 'Metadata Artificat Processing' from Embed in Output Assembly to Copy to Output Directory.

As I can see in your Web.Config everything have been set correctly so there is no need to move anything.

Answer (score 1):

The metadata files contain the table to object mapping configuration for [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937723). There is no need to move them. The application is using Entity Framework as ORM. You might want to check the link and learn how it works.

Answer (score 0):

In Sql Server Configuration Manager (Start -> Sql Server -> Configuration Tools), Can you check that "TCP/IP" and "Named Pipes" are enabled (in Sql Server Network Configuration). At times it is related to that as well.